# OpenCV Face Recognition: Index Out Of Range updating Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox.Image

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

So I'm working on a little app to recognize faces as people walk into my room in order to shout things at them (Mature, I know).

Problem is, I have the face recognition recognizing faces, but drawing it to the screen is being problematic. Strictly speaking, it does not need to draw anything to the screen, but I just want to see it working.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace OpenCVApp1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
        private Capture cap = new Capture(0);
        private CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier("..\\..\\Resources\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
        Thread camWorker;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;

            cap = new Capture(0);
            camWorker = new Thread(() => {
                while (true) {
                    Image<Bgr, byte> frame = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
                    Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = frame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                    Rectangle[] faces = cascade.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10);
                    foreach (Rectangle face in faces) {
                        frame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    }
                    imgCamUser.Image = frame;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });

            camWorker.Start();
        }

        private void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            camWorker.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

It works for a few frames, correctly draws a box around faces, and then just throws a:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: OpenCV: index is out of range
```

And that's it. I'm using OpenCV 3.10, and Emgu for the .NET wrapper.

[image: Some info removed]

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown in most cases when the Image object you are going to show in the ImageBox isn't containing any image. That means number of rows and columns are zero (dimention is 0x0 ). You can check that with debugger by adding a Breakpoint to the place `imgCamUser.Image = frame;` Here you can see whether that is the problem. If that is the problem (If image size is 0x0 ) most probably problem is with the way you use the `Capture` to assign an image to `frame`.